# I keep getting errors like 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get' and 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the youtube water mark a element href but I can't seem to grab it.

if I try

```
    def youtube_link(url):
        youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soupdata.find_all('a', {'class': 'ytp-watermark'})
        entries = video_row.get('href')

        return entries
```

I get

```
'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'
```

If I try

```
        def youtube_link(url):
        youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soupdata.find('a', {'class': 'ytp-watermark'})
        entries = video_row.get('href')

        return entries
```

I get

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

If I try

```
        def youtube_link(url):
        youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soupdata.find('a', {'target': '_blank'})
        entries = video_row.get('href')[24]

        return entries
```

I get a single character

```
's'
```

if i try

```
        def youtube_link(url):
        youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soupdata.find('a', {'target': '_blank'})[24]
        entries = video_row.get('href')

        return entries
```

i get

```
24
```

if i try

```
        def youtube_link(url):
        youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soupdata.find('a', {'target': '_blank'})[24:]
        entries = video_row.get('href')

        return entries
```

I get

```
unhashable type: 'slice'
```

if I try

```
def panties():
    from lxml import html
    pan_url = 'http://www.panvideos.com'
    shtml = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(shtml.text, 'html5lib')
    video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'video'})

    def youtube_link(url):
        youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soupdata.find('a', {'target': '_blank'})
        entries = [{'text': div.get('href'),
                    } for div in video_row][24]


    return entries
```

I get

```
'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get'
```

if i try

```
    def youtube_link(url):
        youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soupdata.find_all('a', {'class': 'ytp-title-link'})
        entries = [{'text': div.get('href'),
                    } for div in video_row]

        return entries
```

I get

```
 []
```

If I use the chrome inspect and hover over the water mark I get

```
        <a class="ytp-watermark yt-uix-sessionlink" target="_blank" aria-label="Watch on www.youtube.com" data-sessionlink="feature=player-watermark" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjww1pgKgnU" data-layer="7">
        <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 77 34" width="100%">
            ........
        </svg>
    </a>
```

but if I use the search ability of inspect and type _blank I get

```
<a class="ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink" target="_blank" data-sessionlink="feature=player-title" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjww1pgKgnU">
        <span class="ytp-title-playlist-icon" style="display: none;">
        .....
        </span>
    <span>Packer Luther King Feat  Mgp the Saw -BIEN MALA (Video Oficial)</span></a>
```

neither one of these are returning results. Is my syntax wrong? any help will be appreciated

this is my whole function

```
def panties():
        from lxml import html
        pan_url = 'http://www.panvideos.com'
        shtml = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(shtml.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'video'})

        def youtube_link(url):
            youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
            video_row = soupdata.find('a', {'class': 'ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink'})
            entries = [{'text': div.get('href'),
                        } for div in video_row]


            return entries

        entries = [{'text': div.h4.text,
                    'href': div.a.get('href'),
                    'tube': youtube_link(div.a.get('href')),
                    } for div in video_row][:1]

        return entries
```

It gets fed a url, uses that url as a way to get the detail page and from that page get that info and return it. For some reason a link is being returned as None. If I try find all or find it will not return a single a element. But if I look for h1 it will work.

EDIT I have tried different parsers

html.parser, lxml, and html5lib

EDIT:

I believe the data can't be scraped because it is coming from the media player. when I did

```
 video_row = soupdata.find_all('body')
```

the data I was looking for did not show up. So It's not me and I don't think it's a bug or anything it's just not obtainable by the normal means. Link tags meta tags and a few other tags can not be grabbed.

Comment: If `soupdata.find_all()` returns `[]`, that means that the element does not exist in the document. Perhaps the watermark is added dynamically using JavaScript, in which case it will appear in Chrome, but not the document downloaded using `requests.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

When I used full value for the class I got the href...

```
video_row = soupdata.find('a', {'class': 'ytp-watermark yt-uix-sessionlink'})
```

and if you want to use findAll you have to iterate over entries. for example create yourself additional list entries_final and do this:

```
video_rows = soupdata.findAll('a', {'class': 'ytp-watermark yt-uix-sessionlink'})
entries_final = []
for row in video_rows:
    entries_final.append(row.get('href'))
```

and then `return entries_final`

Comment: my error when I try that 'NoneType' object is not iterable If I do find_all it returns square brackets [] only

Comment: my error 'NoneType' object is not iterable. I'm using this in a django app if that makes a difference. and also I want the youtube link not the the panvideo link

Comment: I'm starting to think the site is blocking me somehow